# Storing .pdf files in JavaEE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, file-upload, jsf-2, file-io, glassfish

I'm developing a JavaEE application (UI: Jsf, DataBase: Mysql, App. server: Glassfish, and iText for generate pdf).

On of the pages, after clicking the "Generate" button, one pdf file will created.
This file will be saved somewhere.
On another page, the user can load this file.

The solution, after I'm searching:
What is the standard solution, to store the pdf file? (Speed, Security problems, etc.)
In database (BLOB type), or on the file system?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to store it while the user navigates to the next page, I'd use either temp files or just keep the file in memory in the session.

If you want to store the PDFs longer, the easiest is to use BLOBs in your DB. However, this might lead to problems in operations, since the database might (depending on the number and size of your PDFs) become rather large. To avoid this, store it on the file system. Check out https://xadisk.java.net/.

From a security perspective, using any solution should not make a big difference. If someone gets on your disk, there isn't a big difference between reading your DB files or other files.

Comment: Thank you! I check the library, what you advised.

Comment: If you need the act of storing, retrieving and deleting to be part of a transaction or transactionally sound then storing the PDFs in a DB is the way to go. Using the file system is not transactionally sound unless you have a JTA adapter and a connector which will support this. That adds complexity for little benefit. You could try the above mentioned XADISK. However, its certainly not as widely used or tested as the popular DB connectors, drivers etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said storing the PDFs in the DB is the easiest way. But the downside is, once the DB get's big, backup and restore take a long time. Plus I heard of problems restoring multi GB MySQL databases.